# Checking if a variable is a list of unicode strings or just 1 unicode string

Tags: python, string, unicode

Im trying to determine if a list of unicode strings is present or just a single unicode string. Of course Id like to take action on both, print the items from the list or print the single string.

Ive attempted to use `if isinstance(variable_here, basestring):` however as the variable is a list of strings i think its being identified as `True` in both counts. Any help would be appreciated

**Example**

Variable could have either 1 item or multiple.

[u'one']

[u'one', u'two']

Comment: `isinstance(u"foo",unicode)`?

Comment: its a variable, and always going to be a unicode list of strings or a unicode string so that wornt work I dont think

Comment: I am a bit confused, what are you checking for exactly? how would `isinstance(variable_here, basestring)` return True for a list?

Comment: I want to know if its a list or not a list

Comment: `isinstance(variable_here, list)`?

Comment: Will try ^ and see what happens

Comment: That will 100 percent work if you actually have a list, are you sure you don't have a json string?

Comment: When you say "list of strings" what do you mean exactly? Give us an example.

Comment: lol yes im sure i dont have a json string, ill add an example in question. Thanks for the down vote though (thumbs up)

Comment: do `type(variable_here)`. Use data type returned by this statement within `isinstance` and that will definitely work

Comment: Both examples look likes lists so not sure what you are actually asking, do you actually want to check the length of the list?

Comment: added one more answer. I hope that is what you want to achieve. Your question is little vague. Let me know if it is not what you want. I'll delete it before it is down voted like my another answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
if any(not isinstance(variable, unicode) for variable in variable_here):
     print 'Not a unicode list'
else:
     var_len = len(variable_here)
     if var_len == 1:
         print 'single object'
     elif var_len > 1:
         print 'multiple object'
     else:
         print 'empty list'
```

Comment: Note that if you *do* pass this a Unicode string (not a list), it will treat it as a list of Unicode characters due to duck typing.

Comment: As per the question, `variable_here` will always be of the `list` type. I clarified that from the OP.

Comment: I was simply clarifying the point for someone who might come across this answer later. On StackOverflow you can't assume that the only person who will use an answer is the one who asked the question.

Comment: I agree you on that :)